# Files limited access with android applications

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I occasionally develop personal applications with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.5.4 and Xamarin.android.
When the target platform is android 9 no problem to read/write files in all the space of Phone or SD.
With android12, only application-specific directories or files (in Android > data > appName > ...) are accessible. Access to roots file is denied.
I tried to use "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE manifest. No visible effect.

Is there a directive of Xamarin or a parameter of android allowing to access all files of the phone.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to allow access to any files (only multimedia were allowed) in android settings.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Slzv.jpg)

Comment: I’m trying to get better understanding of the file access mechanism. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is required to give access to any files in Android settings. At this time I have not found any permission that gives directly access withouf android setting. To be continued. Comments are welcome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Allow access to any files (only multimedia were allowed)
   programmatically:

Add the following code into the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And request this permission at run time:

```
var status = Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.RequestAsync<Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.StorageWrite>();
```

**Note:the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission was removed in the android 13.0.**

2. Is there a directive of Xamarin or a parameter of android allowing to access all files of the phone.

Add the following code into the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And request this permission at run time:

```
if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
             {
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission);
                 Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromParts("package", this.PackageName, null);
                 intent.SetData(uri);
                 StartActivity(intent);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

My program correctly runs with statments such as

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and

```
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Denied) ListePerms.Add(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
```

But if I try

```
Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager
```

an error occurs I cann't catch in release mode.
In debug mode, no error and value is true.